# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'schema' of null

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

Getting the error accessing store IS to itemselector field, I have not use model, just using hardcoded values for test.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'schema' of null 
VM398 ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1444203173414:51423

Itemselector:

```
items:[{
    xtype: 'itemselector',
    name: 'itemselector',
    id: 'itemselector-field',
    imagePath: '../ux/images/',
    store: 'IS',
    displayField: 'period',
    valueField: 'period',
    value:'period',
    allowBlank: false,
    msgTarget: 'side',
    fromTitle: 'Available',
    toTitle: 'Selected'
}]
```

Store:

```
Ext.define('Myapp.store.IS', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    /* requires: [
        'Myapp.model.JobNode',
        'Ext.util.Sorter'
    ], */

    alias: 'store.IS',
    fields: ['period'],
    data: {
        'period': [
            '20140525','20140625'
        ]
    },
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'reader'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you set a fiddle?

Comment: Fiddle doesn't give a result

Comment: Should be `store: {type: 'IS'}`

Comment: not working, the Ext js compiler function called is                             extractData: function(root, readOptions) {
        var me = this,
            entityType = readOptions && readOptions.model ? Ext.data.schema.Schema.lookupEntity(readOptions.model) : me.getModel(),
            schema = entityType.schema,

Answer (score 0):

```
use Ext.create('Myapp.store.IS')
```

Comment: store : Ext.create('Myapp.store.IS'),